# The theme directory "Divi" does not exist

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I deleted 'Divi' theme and installed new theme TwentySeventeen, but when i'm reloading my home page it showing error "The theme directory "Divi" does not exist."
Plz help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the Divi theme is still chosen as the page theme in the website settings.

In the Dashboard, go to `Design > Themes`. On that page, activate the Twentyseventeen theme by clicking the "Activate" button which appears when you hover over the theme preview image.

Comment: I activated TwentySeventeen after installing it, but still my website was working on Divi. Then i deleted Divi, and then it started showing "The theme directory “Divi” does not exist"

Comment: thanks for solution. I got this and my problem is solved.